# Asp.net GridView Footer Row Textbox Focus Event Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a footer row having textbox for Qty in Gridview.. Markup is as follows:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvProdIssue" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="True" CssClass="table table-responsive table-hover table-light table-bordered table-sm rounded" DataKeyNames="ID,FromProcessID,ToProcessID,MldID,MachineID,IssEmpID" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvProdIssue_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowCommand="gvProdIssue_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="gvProdIssue_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="gvProdIssue_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="gvProdIssue_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="gvProdIssue_RowUpdating" >
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="thead-dark" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Machine">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList id="ddlEditMachine" runat="server" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm"></asp:DropDownList>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList id="ddlNewMachine" runat="server" CssClass="myFocus form-control form-control-sm"></asp:DropDownList>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblMachine" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Machine") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Issue Quantity">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditIssQty" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm onlyNum text-lg-right" Text='<%# Bind("IssQty") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewIssQty" runat="server" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm onlyNum" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblIssQty" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("IssQty") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
</columns>
<asp:GridView>
```

I want a JQuery function which calls when txtNewIssQty textbox gets focus..
How to achieve this>?

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
```

You can try Like this:

```js
$("#txtNewIssQty").click(function(){
   //Code you want
   //Demo Code
   $("#txtNewIssQty").val("Test");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<input type="text" id="txtNewIssQty">
</div>
```